# Choosing between which HTTP, DB, Optimization tools on a VPS server

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, optimization

I am finally moving from a Shared hosting to a VPS hosting on Digital Ocean.

Since now I have control of what I can install, I would like to know which of these are preferred to install.

**Web Server**

Apache or NGinx?

I learn that nginx is faster than Apache but Apache has most support. I am not really familiar with both of them. I just want to know which one is better to use, which one is more stable?

**Database**

MySQL or MariaDB?

I am familiar with MySQL, I just learn that MariaDB is faster, but I am not sure if it's ready for production

**Optimization**

APC + (memcached || redis)?

APC is the only one i know, any better alternative? as of Memcache and redis, I am not familiar with any of them and they are the only one I know.

Thank you

Comment: Answer: It Depends.™

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you Facebook? Are you Twitter? If the answer to both of those question is "no", then stop worrying about what is "faster". Premature optimisation is a bad trap to fall into.

I see too damn many people making choices based around raw speed and benchmarks. This is a bad idea. You should choose the platform based on:

1. What you know best
2. What is most supported
3. What is most mature

(in that order, usually, but not always).

Make your pick between Apache and NGinx. Apache is more common, but both are fine.

MySQL or MariaDB? Never heard of MariaDB so that probably fails #2 and #3 and you *already* state that you know MySQL. So clear winner there.

Memcached/Redis? Both are popular. Both are good. Flip a coin. Decide if you even need it based on the volume of traffic you expect - perhaps just a normal database will do fine.

Basically - get a production ready, stable product out there before you start fretting over things like this.

Comment: Yes, and Yes and tumblr and picassa and also others

Comment: If you're facebook, twitter, tumbler, pintrest, stack exchange, etc, then you'd probably better hire someone with lots of experience in the area

Comment: How much would you charge me? I can pay up to $200/h

Comment: @Timmy - I don't do consulting work - but I will ask someone I know who does to drop you a line and you can discuss with them if you would like.

Comment: sure tell him to send me a message on serverfault, thanks

Comment: @Timmy Check my ServerFault profile and email me at my gmail address.